# PHP CURL can't login to web page

Tags: php, curl, authentication

I'm trying to login to a webpage using PHP and CURL.
The login form on the webpage is the following:

```
<form action="http://utenti.xxxxx.it/ppnew2_jslogin.phtml" name="login_form" method="post">
<div id="reglink">

<a href="/abbonamenti/"><span>Registrati</span></a>
</div>
<input type="hidden" name="action" value="userlogin">

<label for="login" id="loginlabel">Nome utente:</label>
<input type="text" name="username" value="" id="login">

<label for="password" id="passwordlabel">Password:</label>
<input type="password" name="password" value="" id="password">

<input type="hidden" name="okurl" value="http://www.xxxxx.it/">
<input type="hidden" name="articolo" value="{ARTICOLO}">
<input type="hidden" name="azione" value="Entra">

<input class="header_button" type="submit" name="submit" value="&nbsp;&nbsp;" alt="invia" title="invia">
</form>
```

and my php code is made this way:

```
$postdata = "username=".$username."&password=".$password."&action=".$action."&okurl=".$okurl."&articolo=".$articolo."&azione=".$azione."&submit=".$submit.""; 
$cookiefile = '/tmp/curl-session';


    //initial request with login data

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://utenti.xxxxx.it/ppnew2_jslogin.phtml");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Ubuntu Chromium/32.0.1700.107 Chrome/32.0.1700.107 Safari/537.36');     echo curl_error($ch);
    curl_setopt($ch,    CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER,         true); 
    curl_setopt($ch,    CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION,         true); 
    curl_setopt($ch,    CURLOPT_FAILONERROR,         false); 
    curl_setopt($ch,    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION,        false); 
    curl_setopt($ch,    CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT,         true); 
    curl_setopt($ch,    CURLOPT_HEADER,             true); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookiefile);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookiefile);
    curl_setopt($ch,    CURLOPT_POST,                 true); 
    curl_setopt($ch,    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,        true); 
    curl_setopt($ch,    CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,     30); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postdata);

    print_r(curl_error($ch));
    $result = curl_exec($ch); 

    // Then, once we have the cookie, let's use it in the next request: 
    //another request preserving the session
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "www.xxxxx.it");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "");
    curl_setopt($ch,    CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER,         true); 
    //curl_setopt($ch,    CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION,         true); 
    //curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookiefile );
    curl_setopt($ch,    CURLOPT_FAILONERROR,         false); 
    curl_setopt($ch,    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION,        true); 
    curl_setopt($ch,    CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT,         true); 
    curl_setopt($ch,    CURLOPT_HEADER,             false); 
    curl_setopt($ch,    CURLOPT_POST,                 false); 
    curl_setopt($ch,    CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,     30); 
    $result1 = curl_exec($ch); 
    curl_close($ch);  


    echo $result;
```

I want to log in and then keep the session for the next request, but I can't figure out why the log in is not working. I send all the variables listed in the form but nothing...
Do you have any idea?

Comment: You have the url `www.xxxxx.it` defined, when the form should be posting to `http://utenti.xxxxx.it/ppnew2_jslogin.phtml`

Comment: sorry, the first is set to http://utenti.xxxxx.it/ppnew2_jslogin.phtml, i'll edit the post.

Comment: After the first request, what is `$result`?

Comment: $result is the web page with the login form, so I'm not logged in, beacuse for logged users the login form is replaced by a welcome text

Comment: you're not urlencoding your data. if your username or password have any weird characters, like a space, you need to urlencode it. that's probably why you can't login. also, don't set CURLOPT_POST to false, set CURLOPT_HTTPGET to true.

Comment: ok, now the first `$result` variable contains the `http://utenti.xxxxx.it/ppnew2_jslogin.phtml` file, but I'm not logged in